# index size impact on search speed (to store or not to store)

Tags: performance, solr, lucene

right now, we are using Solr as an fulltext index, where all fields of the documents are indexed but not stored.
There are some million documents, index-size is 50 GB. Average query-time is around 100ms.

To use features like Highlighting, we are thinking about to: additional store text. But, that could double the size of the index-files.

I know there is absolutely no (linear) relation between index size and query time. Rising the documents on factor 10 results in nearly no difference of query time.

But at all, the system (Solr/Lucene/Linux/...) has to handle more informations - the index files (for example) are based on much more I-nodes, and so on.

So I'm sure, there is an impact on query time in relation to the index-size. (But: is this noticeably?)

1st:
Do you think, I'm right?
Did you have any experiences on index-size and search speed in relation to with/without stored text?
Is it smart and reasonable to blow up the index by storing the documents?

2nd:
Do you know, how Solr/Lucene handled stored text? Maybe in separate files? (So that there is no impact for simples searches, where no stored text is needed!?)

Thank you.

Comment: May I know if my answer has been useful? Were you looking for something else?

Comment: I wrote this question in order to get an feeling about the impact of index size depending on search speed - maybe from somebody who has practical experience. So an "I don't think" does not relay helps me. Bout your link to the lucene file doc was useful.

Comment: Well, I do have practical experience and I've never had performance problems making fields stored, while I've had size problems. Furthermore the link proves that making fields stored doesn't decrease performance. Doesn't this answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's absolutely true that the index grows if you make big fields stored, but if you want to highlight them, you don't have other ways. I don't think the speed will be decreased that much, maybe just because you need to download more data retrieving results, but it's not that relevant.

Regarding the lucene index format and the different files within the index you can have a look [here](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_0/fileformats.html#file-names): the stored fields are stored in a specific file.

Comment: you don't have to store if you want to highlight, you can fetch the original and re-analyze the original content from your db, and then highlight.

Comment: Of course, if you have a db. I'm not sure what's the cost in terms of performance. I mean, it saves space on file system if you already have a db with the data you need, but maybe it's worse than storing fields on performance side.

Comment: you'll have to re-analyze every time, that's the tradeoff. storing fields should not affect search performance since they go to a different file anyway. don't know if this is true with the compound index format..

Comment: @milan re-analyse the original text to realize an highlighting outside Solr/Lucene is what we are doing now. The Problem is, that in fact it's not possible to create valid highlighting outside Solr/Lucene, because you have to handle the terms in the same way like solr does, including synonyms, stemming and so on. So you have to rebuild the solr-kind highlighting on application side, which is a very big challenge - it will never work with 100% same results.

Comment: Then, if you're worried about performance, go ahead! Make those fields stored! :-)